# Program getting split after multiple fork() calls

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, fork

I am unable to figure out why the following piece of code does not produce the result I expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int n1 = fork();

    if (n1 == 0) {
        int n2 = fork();
        int n3 = fork();
        int n4 = fork();
    } else if (n1 > 0) {
        int n5 = fork();
    }

    printf("%d with parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
}
```

I would expect this to print everything at once. However, it prints the first process, and then the rest in a new run of the program. It also outputs the wrong parent PID's and does not terminate.

[image]

Comment: While executing `./main` what is the output of  `pgrep main`

Comment: @LinuxGeek 2503
4572
5973

Answer (score 0):

It's not a new run of the program.

The original parent process doesn't wait for the children to exit. It forks one child with `int n1 = fork();` and a second child with `int n5 = fork();`. Then it prints its message and exits.

The shell is only waiting for that original parent process, it doesn't know anything about the children. When it exits, the prompt is printed.

Meanwhile, the child processes are still running. They print their messages after the shell prompt. It would also be possible for some of them to print first -- the order that they all run is unpredictable.

The PIDs are not wrong. When the parent process exits before a child, the child is inherited by `systemd`, so it's parent process ID changes. That's PID 1256 in your case.

Comment: I understand the printing part now. However, I still do not get why the program does not terminate. Is that just what it looks like because the parent exits first?

Comment: It does terminate. Don't you see the shell prompt before the output `6600 with parent 1256`?